# RDS Size Larger than DB Size after Upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds-aurora

I have an Amazon cluster that's currently at 14TB, when my DB size is less than 1GB. This only started after I upgraded the Aurora/MySQL version to 2.08.3/5.7. It started slowly ramping up the size after the upgrade until it maxed out.

We have dropped entire databases, and the size stays the same.

We compared settings in the parameter group and didn't see anything that stuck out.

I also tried to set the innodb_file_per_table to 0 based on a similar thread I've found elsewhere for MySQL 5.6, but it doesn't appear to have changed the size of the instance.

I've been running this query on a daily basis, but the size in always <1GB (both index and data size together).

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(data_length)/1024/1024) AS data_in_mb, 
ROUND(SUM(index_length)/1024/1024) AS index_in_mb, 
ROUND(SUM(data_free)/1024/1024) AS free_in_mb 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

The fact that we dropped a database and no change happened tells me that something isn't releasing space, but I'm not sure what.

We also don't use temp tables.

Comment: Note that changing `innodb_file_per_table` _only_ applies to tables that are `CREATEd` or `ALTERed` _after_ the setting changes.  Do you know how big `ibdata1` was before the upgrade?  After?

Comment: I don't even know how to see the ibdata1 file with AWS, and google hasn't been very helpful there. I know my innodb tables aren't that big.

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your cluster to v2.09: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-aurora-enables-dynamic-resizing-database-storage-space/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: They also say that Serverless V1 only supports the version I'm on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.ServerlessV1.html#Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.ServerlessV1.amy

The only way I can see I could upgrade would be to create a new instance and figure out how to safely migrate the data over to it.